# TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have been trying out the Django tutorial[Django Tutorial Page 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/) and encountered this error

> "TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/ " .

I assume the problem is with my code pointing the templates file index.html. This is my file structure for `index.html`:  `mysite/polls/templates/polls`. 
I am copying my `settings.py` and `views.py` here.

## settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

## views. Py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from polls.models import Poll

# Create your views here.

#def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You are at the poll index.")

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def detail(request,poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of the poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request,poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

Can someone look into it and help me to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated. 
This is the traceback `Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/polls/

Django Version: 1.6.4
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Python34\mysite\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\mysite\polls\views.py" in index
  14.     template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
  131.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
Exception Value: polls/index.html`
```

Please let me know if i missed out anything that would give a more clear picture. Thanks in advance.

Settings.py """

```
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ma_x5+pnvp$o7#5g#lb)0g$sa5ln%k(z#wcahwib4dngbbe9^='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'C://Python34/mysite/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

#TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to put template folder in projects root folder:

`mysite/templates/polls/index.html`

**Explanation**

Your template dirs is

`TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`

It containts only one directory: `/path/to/your/project/templates`

And your index.html located in `/path/to/your/project/polls/templates`

**Update**

As you say it doesn't work with templates stored in `mysite/templates/polls/index.html` let's try this way:

go to mysite and run

```
python manage.py shell
```

to run interactive interpreter with `mysite` as context. Then run this:

```
from settings import TEMPLATE_DIRS
print TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

it will output something like

```
('/var/www/mithril/templates/', '/home/dmitry/proj/mithril/templates/')
```

Django uses this directories to find your templates. 
Thus you should put directory `polls/` in folder from `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Comment: I tried that but still get the same error. This is my traceback File 
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\mysite\polls\views.py" in index
  14.     template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')

  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template
                            

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
Exception Value: polls/index.html

Comment: please repeat: where is your templates stored?

Comment: its stored in mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html.

Comment: Awww man... Move it to `mysite/templates/polls/index.html`
Please read answers properly next time

Comment: I have tried that before..!! its giving me the same error..!

Answer (score 5):

Whoa whoa whoa. Let's not advocate non re-usability of apps.

For templates that don't fit anywhere else (usually your base template, maybe some partial templates like form includes, etc.), it's fine to put them in your root templates directory (ie. `/path/to/project/templates/base.html`). You would refer to them in a view for rendering as `base.html`.

For other templates, I would advise you put them in the directory of the app that contains the views that render to those templates. For example, your polls index would go somewhere such as `/path/to/project/polls/templates/polls/index.html`.

The extra `polls` directory may look redundant there, but the reason is that the django template loader will (logically) dump all your templates in one directory. So we use the second `polls` directory to differentiate between multiple `index.html` templates that may exist. So in your view, you would use `polls/index.html` as normal.

The reason that this is a Good Thing is that it makes your apps more easily reusable. Written one polls app? You've written them all. If you do this, and also keep your app specific static files (js, css, images, etc.) in your app's static directory, and have a `urls.py` for each app, generally all you will need to do to move your app from one project to another is copy the directory, add to the new project's `INSTALLED_APPS`, and include the urls from your base `urls.py`. And of course, modify the app in any way you need to for the new project.

It also means if you're using an editor with sidebar navigation (most of them, these days), you don't have to scroll all the way down to your templates to find the template for that app. When you start working on large projects this gets tedious, fast.

The only thing to remember in using this technique is that you must have `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting. This is the default so you usually won't have to worry about it.

There is a nice guide for this in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/reusable-apps/

To answer the question you actually asked:

Your `index.html` should be here: `C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html`. If it isn't, that's what you're doing wrong.

On a related note, you probably shouldn't have your project in the Python directory.

Comment: Hi Knyght, Thanks for your response. My index.html file is in the path you mentioned above  [C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html.] But i still get the same error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you paste your whole settings file? And print the value of BASE_DIR and check it's correct?

Comment: I have added my whole settings.py file to my question part above. Thanks for helping me out..! I am stuck with this for 2 days now ..!

Comment: Well, a couple of things. TEMPLATE_DIRS shouldn't be commented out, but I assume that is from you testing things. Also, `'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'C://Python34/mysite/db.sqlite3'),` isn't right. When you use `os.path.join()` you are adding the second parameter to your base directory, the directory your `manage.py` is in. So you are ending up with `c:/path/to/project/c://python/etc` which doesn't make sense. Also I think you only need one forward slash after the `c:`. But the second argument to `os.path.join()` should just be `'db.sqlite3'`.

Comment: But really it looks like your code (uncommented) should work. Check that the traceback is still the same. As you can see from this line: `C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html (File does not exist)`, it *is* looking in the right place. Could it be a case sensitivity problem or a typo?

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace:

```
template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
```

with this:

```
template = loader.get_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add your app config in the INSTALLED_APP in settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (

```
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

)

> The *startapp* command creates an *apps.py* file. Since it doesn’t use *default_app_config* (a
>   discouraged API), you must specify the app config’s path, e.g. *'polls.apps.PollsConfig'*, in
>   *INSTALLED_APPS* for it to be used (instead of just *'polls'*).

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and I noticed there was another HTML file named `index` in `site-packages`. So I just changed my current HTML file to `index1` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you forgot the 's' in

> /polls/template

its

> '/polls/templates' folder.

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py file, add this

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

And then in TEMPLATES DIRS, add this,

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    ...
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
    ...
},]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your folder structure. Since you are inside the `polls` folder, you should have this `template = loader.get_template('index.html')` instead of `template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')`

This is because of how the python path works, see here [OS Path](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 0):

You follow this structure,

```
mysite/
   mysite/
      templates/
         polls/
           index.html
```

there's something suspect to your TEMPLATE_DIRS path. It should point to the root of your template directory.

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

In your error log django searching these paths,

```
C:\Python34\mysite\templates\polls\index.html 
C:\Python34\mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html
```

Comment: That hasn't been the recommended way of doing things for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't misspell detail.html as details.html. This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should have placed your templates inside poll app inside `templates/polls/` structured. Such that the full path will look like `mysite/polls/templates/polls/file.html`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running through the tutorial. None of the above answers worked for me.

my solution:
make sure when you are saving your html files, click SAVE AS and then click the file type and click "All Files". My index.html file was actually index.html.txt and was not being found.